# How can I generate an error which says "Javascript For/in loop not working - Object property is not defined "

Tags: javascript

I tried this code to raise an error but it works fine.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h2>JavaScript For In Loop</h2>
    <p>The for in statement loops through the properties of an object:</p>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    const basket= {
      cup: 1,
      plate: 2,
      mug: 100
    }
    
    function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
      for(item in basket) {
        console.log(item);
         if(item === lookingFor) {
          return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`;
        }     
       }
       return `${lookingFor} is not in your basket`;
    }
 </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I was given a task to raise an error ,but I am unable to do it .Please any One help me

Comment: Where is closing tag for script? </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**call your function with parameter**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript For In Loop</h2>
<p>The for in statement loops through the properties of an object:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

const basket = {
    cup: 1,
    plate: 2,
    mug: 100
}

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
    for (item in basket) {
        console.log(item);
        if (item === lookingFor) {
            return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`;
        }
    }
    return `${lookingFor} is not in your basket`;
}

//call your function
checkBasket(basket, 'cup');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Just call your function with parameter**

```js
const basket= {
  cup: 1,
  plate: 2,
  mug: 100
}

//call your function with parameter after the basket object
checkBasket(basket, 'cup')

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  for(item in basket) {
    console.log(item);
     if(item === lookingFor) {
      return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`;
    }     
   }
   return `${lookingFor} is not in your basket`;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript For In Loop</h2>
<p>The for in statement loops through the properties of an object:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-and-catch block to handle errors appropriately and use the `throw` keyword to throw errors as shown below.

You can refer to this guide to understand [Throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) and [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

```js
function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  try{
      if (Object.hasOwn(basket,lookingFor)){
        return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`;
      }else{
        throw new Error("Javascript For/in loop not working - Object property is not defined")
      }
  }catch(err){
      console.error(err)
      return err;
  }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript For In Loop</h2>
<p>The for in statement loops through the properties of an object:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const basket= {
  cup: 1,
  plate: 2,
  mug: 100
}

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  for(item in basket) {
    console.log(item);
     if(item === lookingFor) {
      return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`;
    }     
   }
   return `${lookingFor} is not in your basket`;
}

console.log( checkBasket(basket, 'cup') ) ;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```